Implementing Row Level Security with Dynamic Permissions in Supabase for Role Management
Imagine two tables:
Website



name
type




id
int



Website Contributor



name
type
description




account_id
uuid
FK to supabase's authenticated users table; auth.uid()


website_id
int
FK to website


role
enum
OWNER or EDITOR



The only scenarios which a website_contributor should be inserted is as such:

When a new website is created, it will auto-insert a  website_contributor to add the current user as OWNER.
When the current user requests to add a new editor into a website, insert website_contributor with the other user and EDITOR role. (The current user must be the website's owner for this to succed)


Question is, how would I go about to handle these scenarios with Row Level Securities or Edge Functions?

If I use edge functions, how would I still make the RLS permissive to my edge function, but restrictive enough for security reasons?


I am new to Supabase and BaaS in general.
Currently I am thinking of creating a BFF, and a secret super-user account.Whereby the BFF would use the super-user account to perform website_contributor operations, and Supabase would set RLS to only allow the super-user to perform those operations.But I would like to avoid creating a BFF if possible.
